# Rails 7/Stimulus: How do I reference an element with a dynamically generated ID from within a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have an `Entry` model. I render each entry using a partial. Below each entry, I have a button. Clicking on that button shows the complete entry within a turbo frame.

When the turbo frame loads, the `#toggle` action is fired in the stimulus controller. Rails generates a unique id for every button using `dom_id(entry, :show)`. (`show_entry_1000529641` for example).

I want to reference the button element in the `#toggle` action.

I understand that the usual way of referencing targets is by first declaring them at the top `static targets = [...]`. But since the target ids are generated dynamically, I'm not sure what to do.

At the moment, I am setting a `data-button` attribute on the turbo frame. Then using that value to look up the button element.

I feel like there is probably a better way of doing this. What is the correct/better way?

```rb
#entries/_entry.html.erb
#...
<%=
  button_to "Show #{entry}",
          entry_path(entry),
          id: dom_id(entry, :show),
          method: :get,
          data: { turbo_frame: dom_id(entry) } %>

#...

<%= turbo_frame_tag entry,
                    data: {
                      controller: "buttons",
                      action: "turbo:frame-load->buttons#toggle",
                      button: dom_id(entry, :show)
                    } %>
```

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  toggle() {
    const button_id = this.element.getAttribute('data-button')
    const button = document.getElementById(button_id)
    console.log(button)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Targets use a name as a reference, not an ID (see [documentation](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets))

The correct Stimulus approach is to have all necessary elements inside the controller and reference these using Target names. The controller `<div>` acts as a scope therefore you can have multiple same name controllers with same name targets in one page and it would just work, no need for element IDs.

There where you would normally use a reference by ID, use `this.exampleTarget` in Stimulus. An analogy for a reference by a class is `this.exampleTargets`. Targets must be defined in the `static targets = ['example']` and in the element's data attribute `data-controllerName-target="example"`

I suggest you try something like this:

```
#entries/_entry.html.erb
#...
<div data-controller="buttons">
  <%=
    button_to "Show #{entry}",
            entry_path(entry),
            id: dom_id(entry, :show),
            method: :get,
            data: { turbo_frame: dom_id(entry),
                    buttons_target: 'button'
                  } %>

  #...

  <%= turbo_frame_tag entry,
                      data: {
                        action: "turbo:frame-load->buttons#toggle",
                        button: dom_id(entry, :show)
                      } %>
</div>
```

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

static targets = ['button']
export default class extends Controller {
  toggle() {
    console.log(this.buttonTarget)
  }
}
```